# Can't show response after post request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble when I try to show the answer of post request with node and request. I can see the response in the console in service, but it does not arrive into controller..why?
Thaaaanks!

Here is the code:

```
function postData(req, res, next){
    eventService.getItems()
    .then(response => {
        const result = response.body.items        
        const id = nameFilter.map(task => task.id =  null)

        for(var i = 16 ; i < nameFilter.length; i++){
            eventService.postData(nameFilter[i])
        } 
    })
     .then(response => {
        console.log(response) // undefined
        res.send(response)
    }) 
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
        next(error)
    }) 
}

module.exports = {postData}
```

service

```
  postData(data) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      request.post({
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '00002'
        },
        url: 'url ',
        json: data
      }, 
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          console.log(response.body) // shows the message
          resolve(response.body)
        } 
      }); 
    })  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the following part of the code:

```
.then(response => {
    const result = response.body.items        
    const id = nameFilter.map(task => task.id =  null)

    for(var i = 16 ; i < nameFilter.length; i++){
        eventService.postData(nameFilter[i])
    } 
})
 .then(response => { // the previous `then` didn't return anything so you shouldn't expect any argument to be passed here!
    console.log(response) // undefined
    res.send(response)
})
```

`response` is available in the context of the first `then` but not in the second! (this is the reason it's `undefined`).

In order to pass it to the second `then` you'll need to add `return response` after the for-loop of the first `then`:

```
.then(response => {
    const result = response.body.items        
    const id = nameFilter.map(task => task.id =  null)

    for(var i = 16 ; i < nameFilter.length; i++){
        eventService.postData(nameFilter[i])
    } 
    return response; // <-- pass it here
})
 .then(response => {
    console.log(response) // and now you'll have it!
    res.send(response)
})
```

Comment: @larry_82 no worries, glad to help!

Comment: this wont wait for `eventService.postData(nameFilter[i])` to finish - so, it seems pointless for `eventService.postData` to return anything, let alone a promise (flaw in OP code, not this code) @larry_82

Comment: @larry_82 if this answer solved your issue, please use tick the checkmark to the left to mark it as "accepted answer". Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in every `.then` in the Promise if you want to use it in the next.

In this case there is not point creating a new `.then` and you code can be changed to:

```
function postData(req, res, next){
    eventService.getItems()
    .then(response => {
        const result = response.body.items        
        const id = nameFilter.map(task => task.id =  null)

        const promises = []
        // Should 16 be here? Seems like an error
        for(var i = 16 ; i < nameFilter.length; i++){
            promises.push(eventService.postData(nameFilter[i]))
        } 
        // postData returns a promise, so above we build an array of all the promises
        // then this line will wait for all of them to complete
        return Promise.all(promises)

    })
    .then(allResults => {
        // All results will now be the result of every call to `eventService.postData...`
        console.log(allResults)
        res.send(allResults)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error')
        next(error)
    }) 
}

module.exports = {postData}
```

Comment: this wont wait for `eventService.postData(nameFilter[i])` to finish - so, it seems pointless for `eventService.postData` to return anything, let alone a promise (flaw in OP code, not this code)

Comment: You're right. I've updated so it now does something with the result, although OP will need to clarify what they want returned